# When can the kernels of two different linear transformations be the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

To add more to what is said in the title, if the two linear transformations have the same rank and nullity, can we say their kernels are equal?

Answer (score 2):

No,  the nullity is just the dimension of the kernel,  you very much can have two different transformations with the same nullity but different kernels.  For example:

on $\mathbb R ^2$,  $f(x,y)=(x,0)$,  $g(x,y)=(0,y)$. They both have rank 1, nullity 1,  but the kernels are orthogonal!

You can have different transforms with the same kernel.   For instance, any two invertable matrices have a 0 kernel.  For a less trivial one, try $f(x,y)=(x,0)$ and $g(x,y)=(2x,y)$

Comment: Then when would they ever be the same, @Alan?

Answer (score 0):

Take the coordinate forms on $\mathbb{R}^2$ : $f_1(x,y) = x$ and $f_2(x,y) = y$. They have the same rank 1, but not the same kernel.